# Am trying to install xampp but am getting erros

Tags: php, mysql, apache

```
6:58:47 AM  [Apache]    Problem detected!<br />
6:58:47 AM  [Apache]    Port 80 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 4!<br />
6:58:47 AM  [Apache]    Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!<br />
6:58:47 AM  [Apache]    You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application<br />
6:58:47 AM  [Apache]    or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to <br />listen on a different port<br /><br />
```

someone help me if there is a way to fix this? I want to connect to my Database.

Comment: Are you currently running skype?

Comment: There is an application that uses Port 80, so stop these application or change the port for the apache server

Comment: No sir previously i was but i uninstall it out, dose it mean i sould also uninstall xampp and reinstall it again?

Comment: Thanks a lot Jens. but how do i find the port 80, so that i can stop the application?

Comment: if this is running on Linux, check `ps -p 4 -o comm=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have Skype running? Skype may use the ports 80 and 443 which are commonly used by HTTP (80) and HTTPS (443). In the settings, you can deselect an option which enables Skype to use those ports. If this does not help, another program (with the process ID 4, see second line) is using port 80. Kill that process and you will be able to run your Apache.